# Table with @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) strategy fetching wrong column of Jsonb type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Problem
I have created three entities with the strategy InheritanceType.JOINED.
Parent entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class A<E extends AJsonContent>  extends AbstractDomainJsonEntity<E, String> {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
  @NotNull(groups = OnUpdate.class)
  @Null(groups = OnCreate.class)
  @Column(name = "a_id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)")
  @JsonProperty("aId")
  @Schema(description = "This attribute indicates unique id of OriginationJsonApplication")
  private String id;

  private String aAttribute;
}
```

First child is:

```
@Entity
public class B extends A<BAttribute> {

  private String bAttribute;
}
```

Second child is:

```
@Entity
public class C extends A<CAttribute> {

  private String cAttribute;
}
```

Here parent has a column of jsonb type whose type is being passed by child entities using generics argument  A and argument should of subtype  AJsonContent.

Now, when bRepository.findById() is called, it returns an instance of B with jsonb column  CAttribute instead of BAttribute.

When I removed C entity completely, then it is working fine. But when it B and C are both together it fetches the wrong jsonb column for B entity.

Comment: findById doesn't return json, it should return entity instances. So if you are querying for a 'B' instance by a particular ID value, you should get a B instance back that only has properties aAttribute, bAttribute, and id. If you are not - what exactly are you getting back? What is in the database row for the ID you are querying, and what is the SQL issued?

Comment: It is returning an instance of B entity. But instead of bAttribute, it is returning cAttribute which is part of the C entity.  bAttribute and cAttribute represent jsonb column of the B and C entity respectively. SQL issued by hibernate is for the B entity and nothing is relatable for the C entity. In the DB, data is properly inserted for B and C, there is no mismatch.

Comment: Step it back - how can anything be returning 'cAttribute' if it isn't in a physical B entity? Either you are getting B entity instance objects back that can only have B properties (and from its parent A), or you are getting C entity instances back. Are you maybe confusing JPA with JSON serialization (Jackson) inheritance issues? Show maybe what you are seeing exactly and include SQL queries and results as I don't see what you can be seeing.